# Printing the whole String entered through standard input

Tags: c++, string, g++

Why does the same program giving different outputs when inputs are given through different methods?

Program 1:

```
int main(){
    char s[10];
    cout << "Enter a String\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "The entered String is\n";
    cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I give input through command line "Hello World", the output I'm getting is only *"Hello"*

Program 2:

```
int main(){
    char s[] = "Hello World";
    cout << "The entered String is\n";
    cout << s << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I'm getting output of *"Hello World".*

What is the difference between both programs? Is the logic the same? How can I obtain the whole string *"Hello World"* when entered through the command line? Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
string s;
getline(cin, s);
cout << "The entered String is\n";
cout << s << "\n";
```

The problem with your code is that the input stream extraction operator `>>` only gets characters up to the next whitespace (so, just one "word"). The `getline()` function gets the whole line.

Comment: Is it necessary to declare s as string?

Comment: Yes, because the `getline()` function only works with `string` and not `char[]`. By using `string`, it can allocate as much space as it needs for the length of line the user types. This sort of dynamic allocation is not possible with a fixed length character array.

Comment: @JustinCarrey, Why would you willingly choose a character array over a string?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the functionality without using in-built string of cpp

Comment: @JustinCarrey: If you don't want to use C++, then use the C library function [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: I'd rather suggest `cin.getline(s,10)` before going straight to the C library. But of course, `std::getline(cin, s)` is much more preferable.

Comment: @JustinCarrey Well again the same question, why would you willingly choose a character array over a string? Have you been told not to use it? Do you want to make programming even harder than it already is?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, your array is only 10 characters long. Inputting hello world would overflow the array and unpredictable things happen.

Comment: Are you trying to say that's the reason why `operator>>` reads only one word? :)